# Import checkbox value from database

Tags: python, checkbox, flask, jinja2

I'm developing a Python-Flask Web application that should work as a wikipedia for politicians. When I create a new politician it is ticked as a draft by default that can be accepted by a higher ranked member. Therefore, when I create the politician page it is **checked** as draft and when the admin accepts that draft, the **draft** value goes to **false**. 
I'd like to know how do I tick/untick a checkbox based on the column value of the attribute **draft**, which is a *boolean* (True/False). Then I want to change it based on my form result. This is an edit function as you'll see:

This is my Politician Form, the one I use to edit:

```
class PoliticForm(FlaskForm):
  publicName = StringField('Public Name', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter politician public name.")])
  completeName = StringField('Complete Name', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter politician complete name.")])
  startDate = DateField('Start Date', format='%m-%d-%Y', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter the politician start Date.")])
  endDate = DateField('End Date', format='%m-%d-%Y', validators=(validators.Optional(),))
  draft = RadioField('Draft', choices=[(True,'Yes'),(False,'No')], )
  submit = SubmitField('Add Politician', validators=(validators.Optional(),))
```

And I want to check that draft row on my **HTML Jinja2** view, which is:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="draft">Draft</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="draft" class="form-control" id="email" value="{{politician.draft}}">
                    </div>
```

Do I need to used the **checked** paramater? How do I tick the check it it's **True** and uncheck if its **False** and then send that change to my controller?

**politicians/views.py/edit_politician**

```
@politicians_blueprint.route("/edit_politician/<idPol>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def edit_politician(idPol=1):
  form = PoliticForm()
  politician = Politic.query.filter_by(idPolitician=idPol).first()
  if request.method == "POST":
    politician.publicName = request.form['publicName']
    politician.completeName = request.form['completeName']
    politician.draft = request.form['draft']
    if request.form.get('date') != 'None':
      politician.startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form.get('date'), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      print politician.startDate
    if request.form.get('date2') != 'None':
      politician.endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form.get('date2'), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      print politician.endDate
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('home.home'))
  elif request.method == "GET":
    print politician.startDate
    if politician.startDate is not None:
      dateStart = politician.startDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
      politician.startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStart, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    if politician.endDate is not None:
      dateEnd = politician.endDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
      politician.endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateEnd, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

    return render_template("editPolitician.html", politician=politician)
```

Any ideas? I'm really struggling with this..

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="draft" class="form-control" id="email" {% if politician.draft %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
```

Or modify the state of the checkbox via jQuery (if you use it)

```
<script>
  {% if politician.draft %}
    $('input[name="draft"]').prop('checked', true);
  {% endif %}
</script>
```